# Onclick and Link only working on local, not working netify server

Tags: next.js

https://github.com/Aaron1357/Uawesomebeauyu-Url

https://whimsical-lolly-2d120c.netlify.app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g94Nl.jpg)

Onclick event and Link tag only working only local, not working netify server

can i fix this? please help me and show me your opinion

Onclick event and Link tag only working only local, not working netify server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Server support node.js?

Please consider to check your subscription on your server hosting provider.

So sorry because not suggesting any brand in this time

Comment: thanks for answer but our Server (Netify) support node.js but i don't use node.
I think maybe window.open() << make a problem what do you think about this?